# Error when running pyaudio test file

Tags: python, audio

I am using a raspberry pi model B with a Logitech USB Microphone, and I have python version 2.7.3 and a new install of pyaudio version 0.2.8. When I try and run the record.py file located in the test folder provided when pyaudio was downloaded, I get this error

```
    ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Expression 'parameters->channelCount <= maxChans' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 1438
Expression 'ValidateParameters( inputParameters, hostApi, StreamDirection_In )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 2742
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "record.py", line 26, in <module>
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 747, in open
    stream = Stream(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 442, in __init__
    self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
IOError: [Errno Invalid number of channels] -9998
```

I was not able to find any working answers on google.

Any help would be greatly appricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the pyaudio code there is `CHANNELS = 2` this is used for recording the sound `stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS,rate=RATE,input=True,frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)`, by changing this to `CHANNELS = 1` it started working and recording audio

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the question do not provide relevant details. Anyway, I walked with similar issue and I just realize that the problem, at least for me, was that I was using the wrong (nonexistent, default) device. So I just passed the device index as the argument of the open call:

```
stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,input_device_index = INDEX,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
```

Where INDEX is 2 for me. I have obtained this index listing the devices with:

```
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print(p.get_device_info_by_index(i))
```

Remember to import and initialize the pyaudio before run the previous code:

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

If you have problems like "jack server is not running or cannot be started" just manually start the jackd:

```
jackd -r -m -p 8 -d dummy
```